# Django Queryset Construction and Update

Tags: django-models, subquery

I have a model with 2 foreign keys to the same model.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField()

class Game(models.Model):
    team_1= models.ForeignKey(Team)
    team_2= models.ForeignKey(Team)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    team_1_post_game_rating = models.DecimalField()
    team_2_post_game_rating = models.DecimalField()
```

If there is a result, a calculation is done updating the rating based on the result and the rankings of both teams. No problems so far, except if a result is edited after other games have been played.

What i need to be able to do (In the most efficient way possible) is find all the games and update the rankings for all teams that were played by either team subsequent to the game that was edited and any team that those teams played and so on.

I could probably do it using a sub query and values list and iterating on the results but of course Id rather find a nice clean way to construct it dynamically and get away without my database going into meltdown.